# list of multiple dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list of dictonories

`list = [{'color': 'yellow', 'isvalid': '1'}, {'color': 'red', 'isvalid': '0'}, {'color': 'green', 'isvalid': '1'}]`

I want to check if 'color = red and isvalid = 1' and 'color = green and isvalid = 1'.

Lets say I want to check if color=green and isvalid =1 only when color=red and isvalid=1

I tried the following and a better method than the following.

```
count = 0
for i in list:
    if (i['color'] == 'red' or i['color'] == 'green') and i[valid] == '1':
        count += 1

if count == 2:

    print("expected colors are valid in set")
else:

    print("expected colors are not valid in set")
```

Comment: okay, what is your problem? The code seems logically and syntactically fine to me

Comment: This will report VALID if there are 2 red/valid and no green/valid ones.

Comment: I would include the failing cases in the code.

Comment: @ThePyGuy is there any better way to write this?

Comment: @KennyOstrom given list will actually fail with given code.

Comment: Go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for code reiview

Comment: isvalid = {i['color']: bool(i['isvalid']) for i in data}; print(isvalid['red'] and isvalid['green']) # don't use "list" as a variable name. That's a builtin class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be what you're after:

```
dicts = [{'color': 'yellow', 'isvalid': '1'}, {'color': 'red', 'isvalid': '0'}, {'color': 'green', 'isvalid': '1'}]

check_colors = ['red', 'green']

result = all(any(d['isvalid'] == '1' for d in dicts if d['color'] == c) for c in check_colors)

print(result)

# set 'isvalid' for the 'red' one to '1'
dicts[1]['isvalid'] = '1'

# try again
result = all(any(d['isvalid'] == '1' for d in dicts if d['color'] == c) for c in check_colors)

print(result)
```

Result:

```
False
True
```